# Como criar um arquivo dentro do diretório users?

Tags: c, arquivo

Para cada pc diferente, a pasta Users/Usuario tbm é diferente, quero saber como faço para criar um arquivo dentro desse diretório. Estava tentando e consegui chegar no seguinte código:

```
FILE *bug;
    bug = fopen("%userprofile%//log//teste.txt", "w");
    fprintf(bug, "start");
    fclose(bug);
```

Mas sem sucesso, o arquivo não é criado no diretório especificado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso voce tenha absoluta certeza que o nome do diretorio esteja certo voce pode "printar" o nome do erro com...

```
//Outros includes
//...
#include <errno.h>
int main (int argc, char const *argv[] )
{
  char* path = pegar_diretorio_e_nome_do_arquivo();
  FILE * bug = fopen(path, "w");;
  if (bug!=NULL){
    fprintf(bug, "start");
    fclose (bug);
  }
  else{
    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Ja adiantando caso voce receba

```
//Error: No such file or directory
```

Seu diretorio esta errado ou talvez alguem tenha deleta a pasta para isso voce tem de criar os diretorios de novo.

Eu criei uma funcao que faz isso, voce so precisa passar o diretorio e o nome do archivo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//
// Cria um arquivo no dir especificado 
// mesmo que o dir nao exista
//
FILE * criar_arquivo(char* diretorio, char* arquivo)
{
  // "M Aloca" as char* que serao usadas
  size_t len = (strlen(diretorio) + strlen(arquivo));
  char* fopen_cmd = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len); //Comando fpoen
  strcat(fopen_cmd, diretorio);
  strcat(fopen_cmd, "/");
  strcat(fopen_cmd, arquivo);

  // O prefixo eh "system specific"
#if (__unix__ || __APPLE__)  // Caso use gnu/linux ou mac...
  char prefixo[] = "mkdir -p "; 
#else  
  char prefixo[] = "mkdir "; // Windows...(?) 
#endif
  len = (strlen(prefixo) + strlen(diretorio));
  char* mkdir_cmd = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* len); //Comando mkdir (criar diretorio)
  strcat(mkdir_cmd, prefixo); 
  strcat(mkdir_cmd, diretorio); 


  FILE * file = fopen (fopen_cmd, "w");
  switch (errno)
  {
  case 2: // Nao foi possivel achar o diretorio
    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    system(mkdir_cmd);
    file = fopen (fopen_cmd,"w");
    break;

  default: // Outro erro
    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); //Opcional
    file = NULL; // ? exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
    break;
  }

  free(mkdir_cmd);
  free(fopen_cmd);
  return file;
}
```

PS: Nao se esqueca de checar o nome do diretorio

```
char* diretorio = "./user\\ 5/log"; //Cria 1 pasta "user 5" com subpasta "log"
char* diretorio = "./user\\5/log"; //1 pasta   "user5" com subpasta "log"
char* diretorio = "./user\\5/ log";//Cria 2 pastas, "user5" e "log"
bug = bug = criar_arquivo(diretorio, "teste.txt");
```

Comment: Boa cara, gostei muito do seu código, vc já até deixou para que funcione em outros So's... Muito bom!!

Answer (score 0):

Bolei uma solução simples porém funcional, para quem não é tão expert assim, porém só funciona no windows acredito... basta apenas pegar o nome de usuário de quem está logado no pc usando a função getenv padrão da linguagem C (stdio.h). Exemplo: `char *nomeUser = getenv("USERNAME");`
assim já temos o nome de usuário, de resto falta apenas especificar o reso do caminho, que pode ser usado concatenando a string do comando em outra variavel. Exemplo:

```
char *nomeUser = getenv("USERNAME");
    char comando[100] = {"C:/Users/"};
    sprintf(comando, "%s%s/Desktop", comando, nomeUser);
    printf("%s", comando);
```

//valor retornado do printf: C:/Users/'Usuario'/Desktop